# Некорректно работает переключение радиобаттонов

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Считаем сумму значений выбранных радиокнопок. При повторном нажатии на радиокнопку нужно убирать атрибут "checked" и пересчитывать сумму. Но все работает через раз, не могу понять где ошибся.

```js
var total = 0;
    
    $('.cell input[type="radio"]').change(function () {

       let sum = 0;
      $('.cell input[type="radio"]:checked').each(function(){ 
        sum +=  parseInt($(this).val());
      });     
        total = sum;
      console.log(total);
      $(".price").text(total);

    });

    $('.cell input[type="radio"]').on('click', function(){ 
        let sum = 0;
        if($(this).attr("checked") == 'checked') {  
            $(this).removeAttr('checked');
            sum +=  parseInt($(this).val());
            total = total - sum
            $(".price").text(total);
        } 
        else {
            $(this).attr('checked', 'checked')
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cell">
    <input  type="radio" id="5d Resume writing" value="100" name="resume writing"/>
        <label for="5d Resume writing">$100.00</label>
    </div>
<div class="cell">
    <input  type="radio" id="5d resume editing" value="50" name="resume editing"/>
        <label for="5d resume editing">$50.00</label>
                        </div>
<div class="cell">
    <input  type="radio" id="5d CV writing" value="100" name="CV writing"/>
        <label for="5d CV writing">$100.00</label>
</div>
<div>
    <sup>$</sup>
    <span class="price">00</span>
    <span class="cents">.00</span>
</div>
<div class="cell">
    <input  type="radio" id="1d Resume writing" value="100" name="resume writing"/>
    <label for="1d Resume writing">$100.00</label>
</div>
<div class="cell">
    <input  type="radio" id="1d resume editing" value="100" name="resume editing"/>
    <label for="1d resume editing">$100.00</label>
</div>
<div class="cell">
    <input  type="radio" id="1d CV writing" value="100" name="CV writing"/>
    <label for="1d CV writing">$100.00</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Если с радиокнопки нужно снимать чекед, значит вместо неё должен быть чекбокс. Смысл радиокнопок в их одинаковом имени и общем выбранном значении.

Comment: мне нужно выбирать только 1 значение в ряду

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let total = 0;
    
$('.cell :radio').change(function () {

    let sum = 0;
    
    $('.cell :radio:checked').each(function(){ 
        sum += parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    
    total = sum;
    console.log(total);
    $(".price").text(total);

});

$('.cell:has(:radio)').on( 'pointerup', function(){
    let radio = $(this).find('input'),
        checked = radio[0].checked;
        
    if( checked ) setTimeout(()=>{
        radio[0].checked = false;
        $(radio).trigger('change');
    },0);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cell">
    <input  type="radio" id="5d Resume writing" value="100" name="resume writing">
    <label for="5d Resume writing">$100.00</label>
</div>
<div class="cell">
    <input  type="radio" id="5d resume editing" value="50" name="resume editing">
    <label for="5d resume editing">$50.00</label>
</div>
<div class="cell">
    <input  type="radio" id="5d CV writing" value="100" name="CV writing">
    <label for="5d CV writing">$100.00</label>
</div>
<div>
    <sup>$</sup>
    <span class="price">00</span>
    <span class="cents">.00</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Написал для радиокнопок. Но, как я говорил в комментарии, радиокнопки для этого не предназначены, и всё это не потребовалось бы делать для чекбоксов. Радиокнопка не может быть одна с уникальным именем, потому что тогда теряется её смысл. Вы в данном случае используете только её стиль в виде кружочка, поэтому приходится бороться.

Comment: Спасибо! Если использовать чекбокс, то как  ограничить выбор только одним значением из всей группы?

Comment: @Vitaliy я если честно не понимаю о чём вы. В вашем вопросе каждая радиокнопка сама по себе выбирается. Из какой группы в ряду там только одно значение? Если рядов вообще нет, и считается сумма трёх по вертикали. Могу конечно домыслить и представить, что несколько .cell идут по горизонтали рядом. Но тогда не понятно, почему вы это в вопросе не показали и не рассказали об этом. В таком случае чекбоксы действительно не подойдут и мой ответ вроде как подходит.

Comment: Павел, действительно я с радио перемудрил. Изменил по Вашему совету на чекбокс и ограничил выбор только одним в каждой группе. Все работает чудесно! Еще раз спасибо!